# Write in a line of a file in Python

Tags: python, file, methods, line

I'm new in Python
I need to write a number in an expecified line and column of a file; when I use the .write method, it writes only at the last line of the file. It's there a way to write something in the line that I want??

Thanks for the time

Comment: How did you open the file?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I think the OP wants to ask if one can edit a particular part of an existing file, more on, can we actually change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `file.write` method, you are overwriting the file each time you do it.

Change the writing mode from `w` to `a`:

```
file = open("my_file.txt", "a")
```

This will append to the end of the file, instead of overwriting it.

An alternative is to pack all the input into a list, and use `file.writelines`:

```
lines = ["firstline", "secondline", "thirdline"]
file.writelines(lines)
```

Or in your loop, use print:

```
file = open("my_file.txt", "w")
for line in my_data:
    print(line, file="my_file.txt") 
    #print >> file, my_data #Python 2 version
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't shown us what you have tried, I'm not going to show you any code in my answer.

Read the file data into a list. Close the file.

Insert the data where you want it in the list. You can insert an element into a certain position of a list, or modify an element of the list in place.

Open a file object in write mode and overwrite the existing file.